# How to merge branches with different case on windows in GIT?

Tags: windows, git, git-merge

My colleague created by accident a branch named develop-client (lower case 'c') from our main branch "develop-Client" (upper case 'C'). We all work on windows. Now, how I can merge the develop-client back into develop-Client? Git in windows sees both branches as one, so when I try do **"git merge --no-ff origin/develop-client"** (when I am on develop-Client), it says "Already up-to-date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either specify the hash of the `HEAD` commit of the branch you want to merge, or alternatively, manually rename the offending branch to a temporary name inside the `.git/refs/heads` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Determine its SHA using command git rev-parse Branch_name and 
merge using command 
git merge SHA1

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on my local repository. It was one commit ahead of remote. I simply renamed the files as Michael suggested:
In

```
.git/refs/heads/<in-lower-case>
```

to

```
.git/refs/heads/<in-Capital-case>
```

As I had also accidentally pushed to remote, I deleted the upstream lower case branch (at Github in my case) and in my local repo, changed remotes:

```
.git/refs/remotes/origin/<in-lower-case>
```

to

```
.git/refs/remotes/origin/<in-Capital-case>
```